# Help in writing formula and forming logic

Tags: formula, validation-rule

I have custom Picklist field called status on Contact. 
my requirement is: we can set contact status to 'On Hold' and save only if the prior value of contact status was 'Active'. else display an error 'only active contacts can be put on hold'.

can we do this using validation rule or do we have to write trigger?

Comment: Yes, You can do this with Validation Rule....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a validation formula you can use:

`AND(
 ISCHANGED(Status__c),
 ISPICKVAL(Status__c, 'On Hold'),
 NOT( ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status__c), 'Active'))
)`

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using a validation rule.

The formula editor has a function called PriorValue, so you could do something like this:

```
TEXT(your_status_field) == 'On Hold' && PRIORVALUE(your_status_field) == 'Active'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Validation Rule in **Contact** Object...

```
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status__c), 'Active') && TEXT(Status__c) = 'On Hold'
```

Hope this might helps you...